# Error in Hartshorne Prop IV.3.1?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the (b) of Proposition IV.3.1 (Hartshorne Algebraic Geometry page 307),is written  that a divisor $D$ on a curve $X$ (over an algebraically closed field $k$) is very ample iff for every two points $P,Q\in X$ (including the case $P=Q$),
$$ \dim|D-P-Q|=\dim|D|-2$$
In looking at the proof it seems that $D$ is not only very ample (over $k$) ie there is $\varphi:X\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_k$ and $\mathscr{L}(D)=\varphi^*(\mathscr{O}(1))$ but the map $\varphi$ is a closed immersion.

Is it an error?

Comment: The curve is projective and a morphism from a projective variety is always closed.

Comment: That's it! Thanks